# API analysis aborted in Eclipse due to incomplete build path

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, lttng

I am attempting to build the lttng portion of linuxtools by source. I downloaded and extracted the linuxtools-2.0.0 tarball. I imported the lttng subfolder to my workspace. This consisted of 28 separate projects:

- org.eclipse.linuxtools.ctf
- org.eclipse.linuxtools.ctf.core
- org.eclipse.linuxtools.ctf.core.tests
- org.eclipse.linuxtools.ctf.parser
- org.eclipse.linuxtools.gdbtrace
- org.eclipse.linuxtools.gdbtrace.core
- org.eclipse.linuxtools.gdbtrace.core.tests
- org.eclipse.linuxtools.gdbtrace.help
- org.eclipse.linuxtools.gdbtrace.ui
- org.eclipse.linuxtools.gdbtrace.ui.tests
- org.eclipse.linuxtools.lttng.help
- org.eclipse.linuxtools.lttng.releng-site
- org.eclipse.linuxtools.lttng2
- org.eclipse.linuxtools.lttng2.core
- org.eclipse.linuxtools.lttng2.core.tests
- org.eclipse.linuxtools.lttng2.kernel
- org.eclipse.linuxtools.lttng2.kernel.core
- org.eclipse.linuxtools.lttng2.kernel.core.tests
- org.eclipse.linuxtools.lttng2.kernel.ui
- org.eclipse.linuxtools.lttng2.kernel.ui.tests
- org.eclipse.linuxtools.lttng2.ui
- org.eclipse.linuxtools.lttng2.ui.tests
- org.eclipse.linuxtools.tmf
- org.eclipse.linuxtools.tmf.core
- org.eclipse.linuxtools.tmf.core.tests
- org.eclipse.linuxtools.tmf.help
- org.eclipse.linuxtools.tmf.ui
- org.eclipse.linuxtools.tmf.ui.tests

In the Problems view I am getting the following error:

**API analysis aborted for 'org.eclipse.linuxtoosl.ctf.core' since its build path is incomplete**

This occurs for all projects EXCEPT:

- org.eclipse.linuxtools.ctf
- org.eclipse.linuxtools.gdbtrace
- org.eclipse.linuxtools.gdbtrace.help
- org.eclipse.linuxtools.lttng.help
- org.eclipse.linuxtools.lttng.releng-site
- org.eclipse.linuxtools.lttng2
- org.eclipse.linuxtools.lttng2.core
- org.eclipse.linuxtools.lttng2.core.tests
- org.eclipse.linuxtools.lttng2.kernel
- org.eclipse.linuxtools.tmf
- org.eclipse.linuxtools.tmf.help

Any suggestions as to why this is happening?

Comment: Sounds like the `org.eclipse.linuxtoosl.ctf.core` project does not have access to all the packages listed in its `manifest.mf` (for examples `org.eclipse.core.runtime`). Is there a reason to build this from source rather than using the update site?

Comment: I work in a secure office and doing development on a VM with no internet access. @greg-449

Comment: You can get the update site as a zip [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/linuxtools/linuxtools-2.1.0.zip) and install it specifying a local Archive.

Comment: I have that. That's why I am getting the error I listed above. When I import the lttng folder into eclipse which contains the 28 projects above. In the Problems view I see the "build path incomplete error" which is what I am confused why I am getting...@greg-449

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me today and here is how it was resolved (after spending 3 hours on solving it):

1. Deleted all the binaries manually (from the problematic plugins),
2. Update the target definition,
3. Debug Configurations->Plug-ins->Select all->Apply->Debug

Hope that helps!